# How to get the value of string in c# from a testmethod In C#

Tags: c#

How can I get the value of "A" from the [TestMethod] below to do a lookup in the [TestClass]? I tried to move it to it's own class and out of the TestMethod altogether, but my application ended up grabbing the next number that was generated and not the one used in the test method.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Classic
{
        [TestMethod]
        public void MyFirstTest()
        {
            string A = "L" + (String.Format("{0:MMddyyyy}",   SafeRandom.GetRandomNext(10).ToString());
            //some test steps go here
        }
    }

[TestClass()]
public class TestScenario
{

    public void RunLookupMyString()
    {

        //Use string above to perform a lookup

    }
}

public class SafeRandom
{
    private static readonly Object RandLock = new object();
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    public static int GetRandomNext(int maxValue)
    {
        lock (RandLock)
        {
            return Random.Next(maxValue);
        }
    }

    public static int GetRandomNext(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        lock (RandLock)
        {
            return Random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't even compile.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @RJM I just want to get the value a from the Testmethod so I can use it in another method.

Comment: Edit your code example so it makes some sense. As it is, your code makes your question very unclear.

Comment: @hatchet. Can you please look at my question again?  I've updated it.

Comment: @MethodMad. Can you please reopen my question? I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a value from `MyFirstTest` to `RunLookupMyString`, you should modify the `RunLookupMyString` method to take the type of argument you want to pass. Then you can pass it by calling the method:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class ManyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public string MyFirstTest()
    {
        string a = "AAA";            
        return RunLookupMyString(a);
    }
}

public static string RunLookupMyString(string a)
{
    string b = a + " [modified by RunLookupMyString]";
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I can modify my answer so it makes more sense, if you want. TestMethods don't normally return anything, and in your example you're returning before you Assert, so that makes no sense...

Comment: So maybe I need to remove the lot to another method altogether and bring it into TestMethod.  It's just a string.

Comment: Well, what are you testing? Normally a test method will perform some operation on your program API to validate that it's working properly. Start with that idea, that you are testing a unit of code that's been written. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx